# Can MSO, SO, SF, and SU have exclusive features?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

The problem with suggesting feature's for any particular site is that the feature is evaluated in the full spectrum of SO-family sites. "Can we get X," one user inquires. "No, that wouldn't work right on Y and Z," another replies.

Is the option open for Meta-exclusive Features, and maybe another set of features that are geared towards the type of activity on SF, or SU? Each of the SO sites have similarities, but they also have their differences.

Perhaps if StackExchange had a nice API, and features could be developed and plugged-in as modules for each individual site?

Comment: Do you have any examples of requests denied because they don't apply the the family? None seem to come to mind

Comment: Lifting vote-limits on CW questions posted at Meta. But that's a subjective opinion, I admit.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14300/dont-count-votes-against-daily-limit-on-cw-please

Comment: Brad, I asked that question. Which lead me to ask this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSO already has an exclusive feature: the "required" tags and the "moderator only" tags (bug/discussion/feature-request/support and status-* respectively).

I suspect it would be harder for them to have *conflicting* features, but features which some sites turn on and some don't are probably simple...

I can see how a plug-in API would be very useful - for instance, a reputation calculation plug-in if you wanted to change how rep was calculated for more than just a simple "n points for an upvote" change. However, I wouldn't personally expect to see anything like that for v1.

Other settings (where it's just a number changing with no logic change) would probably be best done in a config file or db table, IMO.

An authentication plug-in is probably the most likely candidate for the hosted version.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing to keep in mind is that if all 3 sites have different enough rules it feels less like a cohesive whole and will likely discourage participation in sites other than the one you primarily use.