# Do votes to community Wiki questions count towards my daily vote cap and if they do, why?

Tags: support, community-wiki, voting, daily-reputation-limit

Do votes to community Wiki questions count towards my daily vote cap and if they do, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Because a vote is a vote. Don't matter that someone's not getting rep for it.

If not, then you could upvote everything in a community wiki question without any thought. And what's the point of that?

[Pick and choose the good stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14300/dont-count-votes-against-daily-limit-on-cw-please/14302#14302), because it's not all good. Even/especially in community wiki.